# Is there a bug in QUERY() before numeric values?

Tags: google-sheets

I have some data that has numbers mixed with `#N/A` in them, and Google Sheets correctly converts `#N/A` to empty values, but not all of them:

```
=QUERY({"A",#N/A;"B",#N/A;"C",3;"D",#N/A;"E",5})
```

In this case both "A" and "B" rows have `#N/A` before there's a numeric value, and in that case Google Sheets smashes them together. So the first cell becomes "A B", and the second cell "#N/A #N/A".

This seems to me clearly a bug.

On the other hand if the first value in the column is numeric everything works correctly:

```
=QUERY({"A",1;"B",#N/A;"C",3;"D",#N/A;"E",5})
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=QUERY({"A",#N/A;"B",#N/A;"C",3;"D",#N/A;"E",5}, ,0)
```

it is working fine for me.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Interesting. So perhaps there's something weird going on with header detection.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. This [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) says that if the `headers` is omitted or set to -1, the value is guessed based on the content of data. So probably something wrong with the way value is being guessed.